# run ffmpeg in a loop on pngs for efficiency?

Tags: arrays, list, loops, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to embed production data as text overlay into separate frames of animation saved as png files.

At the moment its very inefficient as I need to sample values from the animation scene such as current frame and camera focal length, and so I have a loop that samples the information each frame, runs ffmpeg to embed the text for that frame, then closes ffmpeg and repeats until complete.

If I have two given string list arrays (such as frame number and focal length), is there a way to ask ffmpeg to run a single instance but for each png from its given list it also references the next item from the array to print the text and therefore operate only once the entire set of frames?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

1. Make `input.txt`:

   ```
   file '01.png'
   file_packet_metadata length=50mm
   duration 0.04
   file '02.png'
   file_packet_metadata length=35mm
   duration 0.04
   file '03.png'
   file_packet_metadata length=18mm
   duration 0.04
   ```
2. Encode, using the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter to add text:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf "drawtext=text='%{metadata\:length}':fontsize=22:fontcolor=white:x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
   ```

   For positioning see [How to position drawtext text](https://superuser.com/a/939386/).

Comment: Just did a quick test. The text was drawn on JPG and PAM, but not PNG. I ran out of time and I'll have to look into it later. Until then you can convert the PNG to PAM or whatever as a workaround.

Comment: thank you llogan, this is a great pointer to get started on.